# Gimp, how can I find the positions of a layer?

Tags: gimp, layers

I need to find the x / y positions for each layer. I've googled but I can't find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the python-fu console for that -
go to  `filters->python->console`.
At the prompt, the first thing you need is to retrieve a reference to your
image of interst.

For example, typing `img = gimp.image_list()[0]` `<enter>` will  store the reference to the most recently open image in the name `img`. If there is only one image open, that will be it. If you have several image, you may have to vary the "0" in the square brackets, until you get a reference to the desired image (hint: you can use the up arrow key to re-issue the command above, just changing the number).

You can see which image you've got in the `img` variable by checking is name: just type `img.name` to see the images' name if it has a matching `.xcf` file.

Once img points to your desired image, just type `for layer in img.layers: print layer.offsets` (and hit `<enter>` twice) - those are the x, y position for each layer, starting from the top-most layer.

Example:

```
>>> img = gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> for layer in img.layers: print layer.offsets
... 
(94, 187)
(156, 70)
(0, 0)
```

(NB. the  ">>>" and "... " sequences are added automatically by the Python interpreter)

Comment: Seems `list_images()` has been renamed `image_list()`